# Less: Compile Less to Css in live server

Tags: css, node.js, less

I use node.js compiler to compile Less to Css. Working in Local Server I do like this

`lessc 'path to less file' 'path to css file'` following instructions in http://lesscss.org/#using-less

Is it possible to get file path and compile directly in live server?

Comment: You would either have to ssh into the live server or compile them locally and then push them to the live server. You can't compile CSS files which are located on the live server by running the lessc command on your local server.

Comment: if you are using php on the server you could use this: http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Comment: You can also use Grunt and grunt-watch

Comment: Indeed you can integrate Grunt in your process, but grunt-watch won't upload your files. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-ftpush

Comment: Thanks for answers! I choosed the way of working in local then push files to live